# Not able to link a static web page using reverse_lazy

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I have written some code to develop a social media site. In that, I wanted to redirect to homepage look-a-like which i have created. I tried to create a url for this page, but there is no use. I am getting the error like:

```
    NoReverseMatch at /accounts/signup/
Reverse for 'start' not found. 'start' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version: 1.11.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'start' not found. 'start' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

In this project, there are three apps. Among them, "accounts" is one app. In accounts, I have created the templates folder with three files.("login.html,signup.html and start.html"). The **views.py**  file for this :

```
    from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from . import forms
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/start.html'

class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("start")
    template_name = "accounts/signup.html"
```

And the **urls.py** file is:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"login/$", auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"),name='login'),
    url(r"logout/$", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    url(r"signup/$", views.SignUp.as_view(), name="signup"),
    url(r"start/$", views.MyView.as_view(), name="start")
]
```

How to redirect to "start.html" page from the signup page. I have created start view but still, it is showing error as above. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url(r'^start/$', views.MyView.as_view(), name="start")
reverse_lazy("accounts:start")
```

`^` for pattern start,`$` for pattern end;You use namespaced url,see [Reversing namespaced URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls);

Comment: Thank you, it is working. @Ykh . Why was it not working before?

Comment: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls